# how to add views a sub menus?

Tags: views, routes

What I want to achieve?

I've got a menu with lyrics / blogs, and I want each entry to appear as a sub menu item.

example:

```
[Main menu]
    Blog
        Dooms day
        Get to daddy
    Lyrics
        Your mom
        Brothers and systers
        Stack overflew
```

So, when I add some blog post or lyrics, there is an option to add them into a menu, however each entry add with weight 0, and they actually appear in ascending order.

So, I want to create a view, and just select the title but and order them by descension on the Update time.

I can make them display in the main content window, but I've got no clue how to actually place them as submenu entries.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am asking the same question:

http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55276/a-question-with-views-how-to-let-sub-menus-appear-view-like-the-main-menu