# A question about views and how to let sub menus link to the view like the main menu

Tags: views, routes

I created a view, like products. The path is /products, and the normal menu item is products
and I have a vocabulary with the name products.

The vocabulary's terms list:

> ```
> product-a
> product-b
> product-c
> ```

I used the module "taxonomy menu" to link the taxonomy to the path /products

My question is:
when I browse /products, the page of products views will appear,

```
 <div class="view view-product view-id-product view-display-id-page view-dom-id-fed2ac877a09718419f677c2a601e561" data-thmr="thmr_1">
```

---

but when I click product-a, or product-b or product-c, they do not link to products views.

```
<div id="node-6" class="node node-product node-promoted node-teaser clearfix" data-thmr="thmr_58">
```

How can I get products views when I click on a sub menu item?

Comment: make my question clear:
I have enable the "taxonomy term" view,so when I click the sub links of products ,like product-a(taxonomy/term/1 ) or product-b(taxonomy/term/2 ),they use the "taxonomy term" view, but I want they use the view("products") of their partent menu( /products) . how do it?

Answer (score 0):

By default a link will be created to the full node view, as you described. When you want an item to link to another url, you need to rewrite the url.

To do so go to the view settings page and click on the field you want the link to be different of. Next go to the 'rewrite results' part of the settings schreen. check 'display field as link' and enter the correct url in the 'path' field.

Hope this helps

Comment: check 'display field as link' and enter the correct url in the 'path' field. ? ----- but the path is auto generate by taxonomy ,like taxonomy/term/1 /taxonomy/term/2.... may my description is not clear, I have edited.